# How to parse different parts of a JSON file in Python?

Tags: python, json, parsing, python-requests

I'm making a program in Python that gets bus times from a server and prints them. The JSON file looks like this:

```
{
"errorcode": "0",
"errormessage": "",
"numberofresults": 4,
"stopid": "175",
"timestamp": "28/09/2016 10:32:44",
"results": [
{
"arrivaldatetime": "28/09/2016 10:43:36",
"duetime": "10",
"departuredatetime": "28/09/2016 10:43:36",
"departureduetime": "10",
"scheduledarrivaldatetime": "28/09/2016 10:44:00",
"scheduleddeparturedatetime": "28/09/2016 10:44:00",
"destination": "Kimmage",
"destinationlocalized": "Camaigh",
"origin": "Harristown",
"originlocalized": "Baile Anraí",
"direction": "Outbound",
"operator": "bac",
"additionalinformation": "",
"lowfloorstatus": "no",
"route": "83",
"sourcetimestamp": "28/09/2016 09:44:49",
"monitored": "true"
},
{
"arrivaldatetime": "28/09/2016 10:43:56",
"duetime": "11",
"departuredatetime": "28/09/2016 10:43:56",
"departureduetime": "11",
"scheduledarrivaldatetime": "28/09/2016 10:14:00",
"scheduleddeparturedatetime": "28/09/2016 10:14:00",
"destination": "Kimmage",
"destinationlocalized": "Camaigh",
"origin": "Harristown",
"originlocalized": "Baile Anraí",
"direction": "Outbound",
"operator": "bac",
"additionalinformation": "",
"lowfloorstatus": "no",
"route": "83",
"sourcetimestamp": "28/09/2016 10:32:40",
"monitored": "true"
},    {
"errorcode": "0",
"errormessage": "",
"numberofresults": 4,
"stopid": "175",
"timestamp": "28/09/2016 10:32:44",
"results": [
{
"arrivaldatetime": "28/09/2016 10:43:36",
"duetime": "10",
"departuredatetime": "28/09/2016 10:43:36",
"departureduetime": "10",
"scheduledarrivaldatetime": "28/09/2016 10:44:00",
"scheduleddeparturedatetime": "28/09/2016 10:44:00",
"destination": "Kimmage",
"destinationlocalized": "Camaigh",
"origin": "Harristown",
"originlocalized": "Baile Anraí",
"direction": "Outbound",
"operator": "bac",
"additionalinformation": "",
"lowfloorstatus": "no",
"route": "83",
"sourcetimestamp": "28/09/2016 09:44:49",
"monitored": "true"
},
{
"arrivaldatetime": "28/09/2016 10:43:56",
"duetime": "11",
"departuredatetime": "28/09/2016 10:43:56",
"departureduetime": "11",
"scheduledarrivaldatetime": "28/09/2016 10:14:00",
"scheduleddeparturedatetime": "28/09/2016 10:14:00",
"destination": "Kimmage",
"destinationlocalized": "Camaigh",
"origin": "Harristown",
"originlocalized": "Baile Anraí",
"direction": "Outbound",
"operator": "bac",
"additionalinformation": "",
"lowfloorstatus": "no",
"route": "83",
"sourcetimestamp": "28/09/2016 10:32:40",
"monitored": "true"
},
```

I have no problem returning the first block e.g `numberofresults` by using

```
 info = json.load(req)
 print info["numberofresults"]
```

However, when I try the same thing with `duetime` it returns:

```
File "bus.py", line 10, in <module>
    print info["route"]
KeyError: 'route'
```

I think this is because the same key turns up multiple times for different buses in the JSON file. How do I specify which bus I want Python to get info for?

File "bus.py", line 10, in 
    print info['results']['routes']
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

EDIT: Managed to get it working by using `print info["results"][0]["route"]` etc. Thanks all.

Comment: No, it's because there's no key with that name at that level. Access the elements in `results` in order.

Comment: `results` is a list of multiple items, you need to iterate over them individually, then search for the bus you want.

Comment: How do I specify which one I'm looking for? the JSON is loaded as `info = json.load(req)`

Comment: It's a list, you access it by position: `info['results'][0]['route']` for example to get the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print info['results']['routes']
```

Try above.

Comment: it's throwing this: `File "bus.py", line 10, in <module>
    print info['results']['routes']
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

Comment: I managed to get it working. Your answer was correct, I just had to add `print info["results"][0]["route"]. Thank you.